Node.js abort controller on pipeline behaves differently
These two code snippets work differently. I provided the signal of the abort controller to the pipeline and aborted the pipeline after 5 seconds the program starts.
First code snippet:
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const { pipeline } = require('stream/promises');

async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
  console.log(`${process.version}`);

  const ac = new AbortController();

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Abort!");

    ac.abort();
  }, 1000 * 5);

  try {
    await pipeline(
      Readable.from((async function* () {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          console.log(`Emit ${i}`);
          yield `${i}`;
          await sleep(1000);
        }
      })()),
      async function* (iter) {
        for await (const value of iter) {
          console.log(`Transform ${value}`);
          yield `${value}${value}`;
        }
      },
      async function* (iter) {
        for await (const value of iter) {
          console.log(`Read ${value}`);
        }
      },
      {
        signal: ac.signal,
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Aborted");
  }
}
main()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Program ended");
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

Output:
v16.20.2
Emit 0
Transform 0
Read 00
Emit 1
Transform 1
Read 11
Emit 2
Transform 2
Read 22
Emit 3
Transform 3
Read 33
Emit 4
Transform 4
Read 44
Abort!
Emit 5
Aborted
Program ended

Second code snippet:
const { Readable, Transform } = require('stream');
const { pipeline } = require('stream/promises');

async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
  console.log(`${process.version}`);

  const ac = new AbortController();

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Abort!");

    ac.abort();
  }, 1000 * 5);

  try {
    await pipeline(
      Readable.from((async function* () {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          console.log(`Emit ${i}`);
          yield `${i}`;
          await sleep(1000);
        }
      })()),
      Transform.from(
        async function* (iter) {
          for await (const value of iter) {
            console.log(`Transform ${value}`);
            yield `${value}${value}`;
          }
        },
      ),
      async function* (iter) {
        for await (const value of iter) {
          console.log(`Read ${value}`);
        }
      },
      {
        signal: ac.signal,
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Aborted");
  }
}
main()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Program ended");
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

Output:
v16.20.2
Emit 0
Transform 0
Read 00
Emit 1
Transform 1
Read 11
Emit 2
Transform 2
Read 22
Emit 3
Transform 3
Read 33
Emit 4
Transform 4
Read 44
Abort!
Emit 5

The only difference is how the transformation stream is made. First code snippet uses an async generator function and second code uses an async generator function wrapped using Transform.from utility function.
Second code snippet seems that the program exited abnormally because the try-catch block did not work.
Is it a bug or an expected behavior?
